# Solr substring search with whitespace

Tags: xml, solr, substring, whitespace, wildcard

I want to find `"john doe"` with `"hn do"` search. `"*hn*"` or `"john\ d\*"` works but when query includes whitespace then `"*hn\ do*"` does not work. Escaping wildcards not helping either.

My field definition as follows:

```xml
 <fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <!--<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" side="back" />-->
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `NGramTokenizerFactory` . It will generates n-gram tokens of sizes in the given range. As below

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10"/>
</analyzer>
```

It will works as :

```
In: "john doe"
Out: "jo","joh","john", "john ","john d","john do",
"john doe", "oh", "ohn","ohn ", "ohn d"...
```

And remove the KeywordTokenizerFactory from the `fieldType` definition.

You can also think of using `solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory`

It has another attribute `side`.

`side`: ("`front`" or "`back`", default is "`front`") Whether to compute the n-grams from the beginning (`front`) of the text or from the end (`back`)

It will works as :

```
In: "babaloo"
Out: "oo", "loo", "aloo", "baloo"
```

`KeywordTokenizerFactory` : This `tokenizer` treats the entire text field as a single token.